# Why install OpenStack

Tags: juju, maas, cloud, openstack

I am trying to understand why someone would need OpenStack when MAAS and Juju are available.

I know that MAAS abstracts the machines in order to use them as resources and Juju allows to install services on those ressources.

I also know that the recommended way to deploy OpenStack is to use Juju and MAAS.

However, for me, MAAS and Juju already define a Cloud in the sense that we do not need to know where are the machine and how many of them there are. So what does Openstack bring that MAAS and Juju do not?

Comment: Read the docus: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2133060 - and you might ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MaaS/juju allow you to utilize the hardware that you have one by one, while openstack (this is oversimplification) also allows you to build virtual machines (usually kvm guest), which in many cases significantly improve the physical hardware utilization.

In addition, openstack gives you the following:

1. It provides a self-service portal where end users (not sysadmins) can easily provision resources - virtual machines, networks (private), storage
2. It allows you to meter usage (and as a result bill or cross-charge the users)
3. It allows you to take snapshots, spin up new virtual machines from snapshots, etc.
4. It has a bunch of add on services for application provisioning, such as building hadoop clusters, template-based provisioning, database provisioning.
5. It can actually manage bare metal, kvm, xen, vmware and docker containers from the same interface.

EDIT: Probably the most differentiating aspect that i missed to mention the first time is the multi-tenancy model. Even if openstack is deployed as a private cloud, you can have separate tenants for different divisions/departments of the entity and users from one tenant will have no access to resources allocated to a different tenant.

This is not an exhaustive answer, just a high-level overview.

Comment: Well that's interesting. However, who would need such a complex installation? I can imagine some server providers or schools for remote access, but how can we know when we need a cloud and when we need a dedicated server?

Comment: Umm, lets do some math. One physical server costs around $5k. At 20-30% average utilization, you are effectively using $1.5k of them. If you need another server to host another application, you have to spend another $5k and if you had virtualization, you could use your already existing server and still have some free capacity on it. If you work for a large enterprise, it may take you months to get a server. If the same enterprise had a private cloud, it is a matter of minutes. There are many other pros. And when you have more than 5 servers to manage, the complexity is actually not that big.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely for larger organizations - 200 virtual servers or more. The more virtual servers, the lower overall cost per server and the foundation server cost is spread across more compute nodes. You can read how Intel migrated 17,000 VMware virtual servers to OpenStack and saved $21 million while decreasing virtual server provisioning from 90 days to 30 minutes. The PDF is available on this link: http://www.openstackready.com

Also note that ATT is deploying 500,000 OpenStack nodes between now and 2020. It will run the entire ATT IT infrastructure and eliminate VMware licensing and maintenance. Average cost per virtual machine will be less than $3 per month per VM (includes the server, storage and networking).